# The number of series over $\{0,1,2\}$ without repeating numbers

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

What is the number of series over $\{0,1,2\}$ with length $n$ without repeating the same number one after the other ($22$ is not allowed but $101$ is), that does not begin and end with the number $2$.
The series $10210$ is good. The series $2002$ is not good because there are two consecutive $0$, and it starts and ends with $2$.
I tried recurrence with the following formula:
$a_n=2a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}$
The reason is that the element before the last has $2$ options according to its previous element. But when I thought about the last element I thought that it can be 1 or 0 according the the element before that.
But if $2$ is the element before last I think the formula is not right.
Should I split it to cases (another formula $b_n$)?

Comment: @ Yinon. I think you should change your example string 202 which you first say is allowed and then later say it is not allowed because it starts and ends with a 2.  Also, it is not clear to me whether strings like  201 or 102 are allowed.  Are you disallowing only strings that both start and end with a 2?  The answer below ( I think) assumes that you are  NOT allowing 201   because it starts OR ends with a 2.

Comment: I edited it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the problem but with the condition that the first and last number is always a $2$. This corresponds to the original problem by chopping of the $2$s:

$$2\underbrace{010120}_{\text{original}}2$$

Let $a_n$ be the number of such sequences of length $n$. Then $a_3 = 2$ is the first nonzero entry.

Now disregarding that the second last number may not be a $2$, it is manifest that each position $2 \ldots n-1$ has $2$ options, accounting for $2^{n-2}$ possibilities.

But observe that those sequences with a $2$ at position $n-1$ correspond bijectively to those constituting $a_{n-1}$:

$$\underbrace{21021212}_{\text{in $a_{n-1}$}}2$$

Thus we obtain the recurrence:

$$a_n = 2^{n-2} - a_{n-1}$$

which is readily solved using standard techniques.

Comment: So after we chop off the first 2 and the last 2 ( in order to answer the original problem) I have: There are 2^(n + 2)/6 - (2/3)*(-1)^n length n words on {0,1,2}  with no two consecutive like letters that neither start nor end with a 2.  Do you agree?

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Modulo algebra computations, that's what I got as well. Cheers! :)

Comment: Does Yinon's original recurrence relation, $a_n=a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$, work? The $a_{n-1}$ accounts for those without a $2$ in the second-to-last element, and the $2a_{n-2}$ comes from those with a $2$ in the second-to-last element.

Comment: @columbus8myhw It seems it works, yes. The roots of the polynomial are also $2$ and $-1$, which means the recurrences have the same solution.